# How to know if a range is empty?

Tags: go, go-templates

How can I conditionally display something else if my range is empty?

```
{{range .Users}}
...
{{end}}
```

If the range is empty, I want to display a different block of HTML.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`{{range pipeline}} T1 {{else}} T0 {{end}}`](https://godoc.org/text/template#hdr-Actions):

> ```
> {{range pipeline}} T1 {{else}} T0 {{end}}
>         The value of the pipeline must be an array, slice, map, or channel.
>         If the value of the pipeline has length zero, dot is unaffected and
>         T0 is executed; otherwise, dot is set to the successive elements
>         of the array, slice, or map and T1 is executed.
> ```

Example:

```
{{range .Users}}
...
{{else}}
<p>No users</p>
{{end}}
```

Comment: How could I just check if the .Users count is greater than 0?  I don't want it to loop.

Comment: I agree with @Blankman . What does one do when rendering a table?  One needs to know if there are a non-zero number of items *before* deciding whether to output the table's `<th>` tags etc. Ranging on the `<td>` -  it's already too late.